# Interaction term in a longitudinal study using LME-Model

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, interaction

I have longitudinal data with a pre and post condition where 4 groups where used. The groups where a control group (CG), a control group with high protein intake (CGPR),  a training group (IG) and a training group with high protein intake (IGPR).
I was wondering if it is possible to fit an interaction term between protein intake and training with lmer().
My model would look like this:

`final_model <- lmer(Outcome~Time+Training+ProteinIntake+Training:ProteinIntake +(1|ID), data=data, REML=F)`.

My Question is if it is valid to compare CG and CGPR with IG and IGPR for the **effect of training** AND CG and IG with CGPR and IGPR for the **effect of Protein Intake** and also including the interaction term *Training x ProteinIntake*. I am not really sure, because i will include the groups in multiple in comparisons and due to that i think they will have shared variance.
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether to include an interaction term depends on whether you suspect that the effect of training depends on protein intake, and vice-versa. Your design is similar to a classic two-way analysis of variance, which would include an interaction between the treatment groups to allow for that possibility.

The comparisons you suggest make sense, but they shouldn't generally be labeled as *the* effect of either training or protein intake. With the `Training:ProteinIntake` interaction term, there no longer is a single "effect of training" or a single "effect of protein intake," as the effect of training depends on protein intake, and vice-versa. If the interaction is small you might be able to construct such individual estimates for training and protein intake, but explain carefully to your audience what they mean.

It's not completely clear what you mean by "shared variance" here, as there are several sources of variance in the data and your model. There's an error variance in the linear model, a variance of intercepts among individuals captured in your random-effect term, and variances and covariances of the coefficient estimates from the model. In that sense there is always a "shared variance" in this type of modeling.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @EdM.
With shared variance i was referring to that in the effect of training, i coded both IG and IGPR group as one and CG and CGPR as one (also the same for the Protein comparison). There i include the "subgroups" into multiple comparisons, and i wondered if that would be a problem with sharing variance (i hope its clear what i mean). Or would it be more accurate to include the subgroups first and then include the Training and ProteinIntake comparisons afterwards like this: `lmer(OC~Time+Group+Training+ProteinIntake+Training:ProteinIntake+(1|ID)`?

Comment: @JanSch that extra `Group` term seems to be collinear with the combinations of `Training` and `ProteinIntake` and thus lead to some coefficients that wouldn't be estimated. A standard way to set up this analysis is to use 0/1 for coding the `Training` predictor (0 for control, 1 for trained) and 0/1 for coding the `ProteinIntake` predictor (0 for no extra intake, 1 for extra protein intake), and proceed with the model shown in the question. Then use post-modeling tools like those in the [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) to evaluate differences among the groups.